# Production spin density matrix $R$ in particle physics and quantum state tomography

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-information, density-operator

I want to perform [quantum state tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography). For that, I need to construct a production spin density matrix $R$ . But I am unable to write it. I can write the matrix element for the process eg. $\tau^+ \tau^-$ going to $e^+ e^-$, but I am unsure how to proceed. Is there any example that explicitly shows the calculation so I can understand the process? I searched but could not find any. Any help would be highly appreciated.

An example of a density Matrix $R$ is given in https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.02280